# Communities option not available in salesforce sandboxes

Tags: salesforce, admin, administration

Not able to find **all communities** or **communities settings** in salesforce setup

- It's available in production or developer org
- not available in the sandbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Renamed to "Digital Experiences"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_rebrand.htm&type=5&release=230). Without even leaving a redirect in the menu where the old option used to be, poor usability.

They handled "critical update -> release update" move more gracefully, eh.